# extern structs in C Error: array type has incomplete element type

Tags: c, struct, declaration, definition, incomplete-type

I have two files, `main.c` and `other.h`. I declare a few global variables in `main.c`, and most of them are fine. I can say `extern whatever` in `other.h` and access those variables. However, I defined a struct like this (in `main.c`):

```
struct LSA {
     int myID;
     int seqNum;
     int neighborID[256];
     int costs[256];
 } local_LSA[256];
```

And when I try to access it in `other.h` like this

```
extern struct LSA local_LSA[256];
```

I get this error message

```
other.h:27:19: error: array type has incomplete element type ‘struct LSA’
extern struct LSA local_LSA[256];
```

I've been playing around with for a while, but... I appreciate any help anyone is able to provide!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The structure type needs to be defined before any instances of it can be created.

You need to move the struct definition into other.h before `local_LSA` is defined.

Comment: I see what you're saying... so for clarification, things in a `.h` file will be compiled before things in the `main.c`?

Comment: @ALittleHelpFromMyFriends When you include a header file, the contents of the header are effectively pasted into the .c file at the place the `#include` appears.  So it would also work if you put the struct definition in the .c before including the header, however it's better to put the struct in the header since the header needs it.

Answer (score 1):

The header file isn't aware of the struct definition of `struct LSA`. What you should do instead is to declare the struct in some "lsa.h" then define and allocate the variables of that type in some .c file.

Please note that the design you suggest is spaghetti programming. There should never be a reason for another file to `extern` access some variable in main.c, which is the top level of your program - or otherwise your program design is flawed. Use setter/getter functions instead of spaghetti.

Comment: Thanks! This is my first time working with a `.h` file, so I'm not 100% on how everything fits together, but I do see that if I just define the struct in `other.h`, I can access it from `main.c`.

Answer (score 1):

According to the C Standard (6.7.6.2 Array declarators)

> 1. ...**The element type shall not be an incomplete or function type**.

In this declaration of an array within the file `other.h`

```
extern struct LSA local_LSA[256];
```

the element type `struct LSA` is incomplete type because the structure definition at this point is unknown.

So the compiler issues the corresponding error message.

```
other.h:27:19: error: array type has incomplete element type ‘struct LSA’
extern struct LSA local_LSA[256];
```

What you need is to place the structure definition in the header before the array declaration.

You could write for example in the header file `other.h`

```
struct LSA {
     int myID;
     int seqNum;
     int neighborID[256];
     int costs[256];
 };
 
 extern struct LSA local_LSA[256];
```

Pay attention to that this record

```
 extern struct LSA local_LSA[256];
```

is a declaration of an array not a definition.

Then in `main.c` you could place one more declaration of the array like

```
struct LSA local_LSA[256];
```

in this case the declaration of the array will generate the so-called tentative definition of the array.

Comment: Ah, I think I got, so just create the struct in `other.h`. It'll just already be available in `main.c`.